# FFMpeg on Android: Streaming HTTP audio stream

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I'm having an issue being able to open streams with FFMpeg on Android. I downloaded the FFMpeg code from http://bambuser.com/opensource and compiled it without any issues. I tried adding --enable-protocol=http to the build options and then wrote some test JNI to setup the stream.

When calling av_open_input_file with the URL to a valid HTTP MP3 stream, I'm always receiving -2 (No such file or directory) back as the error code. I've seen other projects that use this method to open streams, so I'm thinking it has to do with my FFMpeg build.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you figured it out? Could you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the --disable-everything option was removing what I needed. From what I can tell it has to do with the parsers being disabled. All is well now!